# Find the largest number (in a range) that has each digit exactly once and is divisible by 11

Tags: python

I was given a task to find the largest number between 1023456789 and 9876543210 that contains all numbers between 0 and 9 exactly once and that can be divided by 11. I wrote a bit of code that technically should have been able to find this number through brute force (Keep in mind this Python 3.6). The code is as follows:

```
print(max(x for x in range(1023456789, 9876543210) if x % 11 == 0 and '0' in str(x) and '1' in str(x) and '2' in str(x) and '3' in str(x) and '4' in str(x) and '5' in str(x) and '6' in str(x) and '7' in str(x) and '8' in str(x) and '9' in str(x)))
```

I apologize if the code looks weird as I am still inexperienced.
When I tried it with the minimum value, it took about two hours for me to get the result. In this case, the computer was still looking after eight hours. In hindsight, it is logical, it was bound to happen, so now I am looking for an alternative approach to accelerate this process and get my result sooner if possible.

Comment: If you're looking for the biggest number in that range satisfying those conditions, I'd say the first optimization would be to start from the top...

Comment: This may be better on [codereview.se] or [tag:algorithms].

Comment: Converting an integer to a string is relatively expensive. Just do it once.

Comment: You could use [**`sorted`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) to sort the string (you'd get a list) and then compare it to the list `['0', '1', ... '9']`

Comment: Start from the biggest modulo 11 number, than decrease by -11 steps.

Comment: You could create a `set` from the string and if it's of size 10 then you have every digit. `if len(set(str(x))) == 10`

Answer (score 5):

The question involves a simple permutation of a 10 digit number consisting one of `0-9`, so this could be generated using [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations), using a string containing all those digits arranged in highest to lowest order

Given the nature of the permutation algorithm is that the output will be "emitted in lexicographic ordering according to the order of the input iterable", thus it would guarantee that the numbers produced will be in the correct decreasing order, starting from the biggest (the initial input).  This would then allow the naive solution where simply iterating through that generator and cast the resulting list of characters into a string then into an `int`, then do the modulus will eventually get to the desired output.

```
import itertools
  
def solution():
    for raw in itertools.permutations('9876543210'):
        number = int(''.join(raw))
        if number % 11 == 0:
            return number

print(solution())
```

This prints out `9876524130` as the solution after 51 iterations.

For completeness, in the spirit of the original one-liner:

```
>>> next(n for n in (int(''.join(raw)) for raw in itertools.permutations('9876543210')) if n % 11 == 0)
9876524130
```

Comment: Interseting, could you explain how do you know you have the biggest one ?

Comment: In the linked documentation, it states that *The permutation tuples are emitted in lexicographic ordering according to the order of the input iterable. So, if the input iterable is sorted, the combination tuples will be produced in sorted order.* Since I sorted the input in decreasing order, it follows that the guarantee that the lexicographic ordering of decreasing number be generated.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to do it more efficiently:

1. Start to calculate the biggest modulo 11 number in the range: it will be the start of the `for` loop, this avoids the `max` function call later.
2. Do a `for` loop starting from the biggest and decrease by `-11` steps. This reduce the numbers to test, avoids the modulo testing for each one, and avoids calling the `max` function later.
3. Convert the number to a string and put the digits/letters in a set. This is an easy way to check you have all the 10 different digits.
4. If the set has exactly 10 elements, you get the right number. `break` as you do not need to spend time with other numbers.

The code will be:

```
biggestm11 = (9876543210 // 11) * 11

for x in range(biggestm11, 1023456789-1, -11):
    num = set(str(x))
    if len(num) == 10:
        print(x)
        break
```

Output:

```
9876524130
```

Comment: Worth noting, this finds the number after 1,735 iterations

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Well it depends, have you timed it ? compared to the other solution ? still better than OP try generating all the number.

Comment: Not timing related. Simply added a counter and it takes that number of iterations until the desired number is reached

Comment: I know the number of iterations, as I checked afterwrards. As you know it was the first answer to this question.. so if second answer is better, it is fine for me. I would be interested by further fair analysis if you take time to time it also. No problem

Comment: I will. Anyway please note this wasn't a criticism. I like your solution. Just added it as a note

Comment: OK thanks for telling so, and do a nice editing of my answer. Just the 2 first words of your comment were a bit confusing about it.

Comment: I timed this solution and the one with `itertools.permutations`, and found that one to be about 50x faster

Comment: I did find itertools faster. It depends on how many time you run it. But my solution is slower.

Comment: @Tomerikoo - "that" solution, with itertools, was 50x faster than "this" one, on which we are commenting. 178 divided by 3 is roughly 50, which seems close enough to what I got.

Comment: @Malo Nah, your solution is not always slower. There are situations where your algorithm can be faster, e.g. where the divisor is big enough such that the numbers to be checked using this algorithm will generate less numbers than permutations.  There are a total of 3628800 permutations from the input, so that if the divisor is greater than about 2439, your algorithm will result in less checks to be required (actually, the first divisor which your algorithm will win is 21 - 2 iterations for permutation, 1 iteration for this; 2439 requires 119 permutations, your solution: 17 iterations).

Answer (score 0):

A short comparison between the suggested solutions here.

- [OP's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66730594/6045800) is - `using_max`
- [Jurgen's improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66730853/6045800) on that is - `using_short_max`
- [Malo's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66730681/6045800) using set is - `using_set`
- [metatoaster's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66730722/6045800) using itertools is - `using_iter`

The results are:

> using_set took 0.1783951
>
> using_iter took 0.0033607000000000498
>
> [other two are still running...]

Code to reproduce:

```py
import timeit

def using_set():
    biggestm11 = (9876543210 // 11) * 11

    for x in range(biggestm11, 1023456789 - 1, -11):
        num = set(str(x))
        if len(num) == 10:
            return x

def using_iter():
    import itertools

    for raw in itertools.permutations('9876543210'):
        number = int(''.join(raw))
        if number % 11 == 0:
            return number

def using_max():
    return max(x for x in range(1023456789, 9876543210) if
              x % 11 == 0 and '0' in str(x) and '1' in str(x) and '2' in str(x) and '3' in str(x) and '4' in str(
                  x) and '5' in str(x) and '6' in str(x) and '7' in str(x) and '8' in str(x) and '9' in str(x))


def using_short_max():
    numbers = []
    for x in range(9012345678, 9876543210):
        if x % 11 == 0:
            if '0' in str(x) and '1' in str(x) and '2' in str(x) \
                    and '3' in str(x) and '4' in str(x) and '5' in str(x) \
                    and '6' in str(x) and '7' in str(x) and '8' in str(x) \
                    and '9' in str(x):
                numbers.append(x)

    return max(numbers)

funcs = [using_set, using_iter, using_short_max, using_max]
for func in funcs:
    print(func.__name__, "took", timeit.timeit(f"__main__.{func.__name__}()", "import __main__", number=100))
```

Answer (score -1):

I think people have given awesome efficient answers, but I worked with your code to use your method and logic to accelerate the time as you requested. Since the number is 10 digits long, we can safely assume that it will be between 9012345678 and 9876543210 (since we want the leading digit to be 9 to get the biggest number). This reduces the range a lot.

```
%%time
numbers = []
for x in range(9012345678, 9876543210):
    if x % 11 == 0:
        if '0' in str(x) and '1' in str(x) and '2' in str(x) \
        and '3' in str(x) and '4' in str(x) and '5' in str(x) \
        and '6' in str(x) and '7' in str(x) and '8' in str(x) \
        and '9' in str(x):
            numbers.append(x)
```

I appended all possibilities to a list to find the maximum of the list and got 9876524130 which is the correct answer. It took my laptop under 2 minutes and my laptop is not powerful at all.

Comment: "we can safely assume that it will be between 9012345678..." What's the basis of that assumption?

Comment: The conditions are very easy to meet, thus there are many numbers that meet the requirements (I found more than 30k numbers that meet the criteria for the numbers where the leading number is 9). If there were none then we could move to 8 being the leading number but in this case is not necessary.

Comment: You should continue optimizing.. as your for loop still looks at every number in the range starting by 9. This is still a lot.  This is one of the main thing which slows to OP code.

Comment: Oh for sure! I was just trying to make OP's code find the solution faster with the least change. I would not code it this way.